# Same or Different Login REST API for Website(React) and Android App

Tags: android, rest, authentication, backend, system-design

I am developing backend for a product which will have both a Website and Android App. For website I am planing to send the authtoken and refreshtoken in httponly secure cookie since storing in local storage isnt safe ,but for android app i would need to send it in response so that android can store it in shared preference , How do I achieve both the things with a single login API . Should I create different controller APIs for web and Android app or is other some other work around?